# Using atomic_fetch_add in C11 to do manual reference counting

Tags: c, reference-counting, c11

I'm writing a library where a connecting library in another language only understands C. I need something similar to `std::shared_ptr` where ownership is shared. In my case manual reference counting would be ok.

[C11 supports atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). I've been trying to find an example of how to do this properly, but every example I've been able to find has to do with C++11, which has operator overloading.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        int integer;
        // ...
        char* cstring;
        void* ptr;
    };
    enum {
        Undefined,
        Integer,
        String,
        // ...
    } type;
    int* refcount;
} value;

void value_retain(value v) {
    ++(*v.refcount);
}

void value_release(value v) {
    if(--(*v.refcount) == 0) {
        // free memory, depending on type...
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that I would need to change `int*` to `atomic_int*`. The function [atomic_fetch_sub](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_sub) says that it returns "The value held previously be the atomic object pointed to by obj.". This leads me to believe my functions would look like this:

```
void value_retain(value v) {
    atomic_fetch_add(v.refcount, 1);
}

void value_release(value v) {
    if(atomic_fetch_sub(v.refcount, 1) == 1) {
        // free memory, depending on type...
    }
}
```

Is this even correct? My concern is that `atomic_fetch_sub` returns what the value *was*, not what the value *is*.

Also what does `memory_order` mean, and what should I be using for reference counting? Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your design is correct except for the type of `int* refcount;` and the incorrect use of pointers. Right now you have nothing for it to point at, so you'll be invoking undefined behavior by passing the (indeterminate) pointer value to the atomic operations. I don't understand why you're using a pointer at all. The type should be:

```
int refcount;
```

and the code should be:

```
void value_retain(value v) {
    atomic_fetch_add(&v.refcount, 1);
}

void value_release(value v) {
    if(atomic_fetch_sub(&v.refcount, 1) == 1) {
        // free memory, depending on type...
    }
}
```

As for the order/barrier semantics, retain should be an acquire operation and release should be a release operation, but using full barriers for both is also ok.

Comment: The struct is being passed by value, and the refcount is for freeing memory when the data type is a pointer to something. By using a pointer to the counter, the pointer to the counter is copied, not the counter itself. Clearly I would need to initialize refcount. I could do a pointer to `value`, but I'm trying to avoid pointer to a pointer and keep as much on the stack as possible.

Comment: I don't think that design makes sense.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got accepted. Think about having an instance of refcount 1, then you make copy of it and retain it, if you use an int rather than an int*, then the original instance still has refcount 1, when you release it, it just got freed, making the copied instance holding a released pointer.